# MySql startup error ' ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file'

Tags: mysql

I have tried every link that is on S.O but still getting the same outcome every time I try to start MySQL. Following is the log from the .err file.

```
2018-01-07T06:58:11.729500Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2018-01-07T06:58:11.731659Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-01-07T06:58:11.731673Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2018-01-07T06:58:11.731679Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2018-01-07T06:58:11.731682Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2018-01-07T06:58:11.731969Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2018-01-07T06:58:11.732068Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2018-01-07T06:58:11.733672Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2018-01-07T06:58:11.745339Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-01-07T06:58:11.761905Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-01-07T06:58:11.906535Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2018-01-07T06:58:11.906692Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2018-01-07T06:58:11.918639Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2018-01-07T06:58:11.919925Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-01-07T06:58:11.919938Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-01-07T06:58:11.920116Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2018-01-07T06:58:11.974340Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.20 started; log sequence number 129183358
2018-01-07T06:58:11.974571Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /usr/local/var/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2018-01-07T06:58:11.974744Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2018-01-07T06:58:11.974853Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 180107 12:28:11
2018-01-07T06:58:11.983233Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2018-01-07T06:58:11.983254Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2018-01-07T06:58:11.983981Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2018-01-07T06:58:11.984032Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2018-01-07T06:58:11.989041Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2018-01-07T06:58:11.989070Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2018-01-07T06:58:11.989136Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2018-01-07T06:58:11.989166Z 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
2018-01-07T06:58:11.989169Z 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2018-01-07T06:58:11.989199Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have some other software that is using the port 3306. MySQL uses this port, but it's failing to bind to it because it is in use. End the other software and try to launch MySQL again.

If you need to have the other software running at the same time with MySQL, you have to change the default port in one of them to some other unused port.

To change the port in MySQL. If you're on Windows, find the `my.ini` file for MySQL installation, open this file in a text editor and look for this section:

```
# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port=3306
```

Then change the number of the port, save the file, and restart the MySQL service.